# How to make mysql_install_db work?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am new with MySql please help me out.
First to install MySql 5.5.7-rc i used this command->

1. `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-plugin-partition --with-tcp-port=3308 --with-unix-socket-path=/tmp/mysql1.sock --with-debug`
2. `$sudo make`
3. `$sudo make install`

Then when i am executing following command i am getting couple of errors.

```
$sudo ./mysql_install_db --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --basedir=/usr/local/mysql/ --user=mysql
```

ERROR:::

```
Installing MySQL system tables...

connect: Connection refused 

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/usr/local/mysql/data for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:
    shell> /usr/local/mysql//bin/mysqld --skip-grant &
and use the command line tool /usr/local/mysql//bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:
    shell> /usr/local/mysql//bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables
Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /usr/local/mysql/data that may be helpful.
Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.
Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you MUST use the /usr/local/mysql//scripts/mysqlbug script!
```

Then i tried '/usr/local/mysql//bin/mysql -u root mysql' and i found

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

But `/tmp/mysql.sock` and `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` don't exist. I checked it...

Please give some suggestion to overcome this problem.

even `mysqld` service is not being started..

Comment: Just a crazy idea: examine the logs in /usr/local/mysql/data for more information

Comment: i did sir but there is nothing..

Answer (score 1):

"connect: Connection refused" means the server's not listening where it's expected to; I understand that an answer a year late might be a bit *too* late but one should start with what the distribution provides or the official builds and *not* a self-made source build of an RC of a quite complex product in the first place.

Maybe those hitting this question will find the accepted answer to that one useful: [bash:scripts/mysql_install_db: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570964)