# bash:scripts/mysql_install_db: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, debian

I am installing mysql-5.5.13.tar.gz in debian 6.0.4. I am following the steps from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html)
When I run the step

```
scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

I get the exception that

```
bash: scripts/mysql_install_db: No such file or directory
```

But file exist in the place. I made that executable too but its not working. I was working in the root terminal. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

I installed

```
mysql-5.5.24-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz
```

Now after executing command

```
root@server06:/usr/local/mysql# scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

I got the message

```
Installing MySQL system tables...
./bin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
./data for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

```
shell> ./bin/mysqld --skip-grant &
```

and use the command line tool ./bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

```
shell> ./bin/mysql -u root mysql
mysql> show tables
```

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in ./data that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.

Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you MUST use the ./bin/mysqlbug script!

and mysql is not started. Please help me should I download another one?

I installed  "libaio" using apt-get then it was successfully installed. but when i started mysql using command

```
bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

I got the message

```
root@server06:/usr/local/mysql# bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
120514 16:10:11 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/server06.err'.
120514 16:10:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120514 16:10:13 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

In the /var/lib/mysql/server06.err file I found following

```
20514 16:15:49 [Note] 
120514 16:15:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
120514 16:17:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120514 16:17:57 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
120514 16:17:57 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120514 16:17:57 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120514 16:17:57  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120514 16:17:58 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120514 16:17:58 [ERROR] Aborting

120514 16:17:58  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120514 16:17:59  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
120514 16:17:59 [Note] 
120514 16:17:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I searched a lot about this but could not get the solution. Any help will be apprisiated
Thanks

Comment: you can install it by apt-get command like this "apt-get install mysql-server" [source](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/debian-6-squeeze#sph_install-mysql)

Comment: yes but i have to install from tar.gz

Comment: do an ls under the folder scripts

Comment: i see in the tuto shell> and not $, dou you have this to in your terminal or you have $ prompt, (may be it's an indication for somone else to help you)

Comment: I see that there # not $

Comment: Set 'language' option in /etc/my.cnf and point it to the directory containing the language files, e.g.:

`language = /usr/local/mysql/share/english`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the archive file name `mysql-5.5.13.tar.gz` I am guessing that you have probably downloaded the source code version of MySQL database. That's why the install procedure doesn't work. To follow the instruction you need an archive containing the binary version, which should have the filename more like `mysql-5.5.24-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz` or `mysql-5.5.24-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz` (depending on the architecture).

Another way to recognize whether you have the correct archive or not is looking into the extracted directory. A source code version will have a lot of files and directories in it including such as `INSTALL-SOURCE`, `configure`, `Makefile.am`, `sql`, `mysys`, `unittest`, etc. A binary version carries directories like `bin`, `sbin`, `libexec`, etc.

Answer (score 13):

You need to install `libaio-dev`

Instructions for Debian-based distributions:

`sudo apt-get install libaio-dev`

Answer (score 0):

do

```
cd scripts
./mysql_install_db.sh
```

paste errors if there are any